# Javascript back button not working on Cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm using this code here to as router to handle pages in single page application (
Cordova ).

```
var router = (function () {
    "use strict";
    var routes = [];
    function addRoute(route, handler) {
        routes.push({parts: route.split('/'), handler: handler});
    }
    function load(route) {
        window.location.hash = route;
    }
    function start() {
        var path = window.location.hash.substr(1),
            parts = path.split('/'),
            partsLength = parts.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
            var route = routes[i];
            if (route.parts.length === partsLength) {
                var params = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < partsLength; j++) {
                    if (route.parts[j].substr(0, 1) === ':') {
                        params.push(parts[j]);
                    } else if (route.parts[j] !== parts[j]) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (j === partsLength) {
                    route.handler.apply(undefined, params);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $(window).on('hashchange', start);
    return {
        addRoute: addRoute,
        load: load,
        start: start
    };
}());
```

and this router is used like this:

```
router.addRoute('', function() {
    document.getElementById("bodyDiv").innerHTML = homePageHtml;
});
router.addRoute('page1', function() {
    document.getElementById("bodyDiv").innerHTML = page1Html;
});
```

i want to add back button to my application but it didn't work. i did try

> window.history.back();
>
> history.go(-1);
>
> navigator.app.backHistory();

but none of them worked the way it suppose to work.
when i open the application on google chrome, it working just fine but when i convert it to mobile application using Cordova the back button doesn't work as expected sometimes the back button instead of taking you to the previous page it refresh the current one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

> This is only an example for backbutton press.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function () {       
        exitAppPopup();        
}, false);

function exitAppPopup() {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure if you understand my question, your code make you to exit the app, i don't want that what i want is to go to the previous page not to exit from the app

Comment: @ler Can't you assign previous page to a variable.? on backbutton pressed you can call 'window.location=the_variable'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried something like this?

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", back_function, false);

function back_function() {
    // Handle event
}
```

Comment: yes of course that obvious the problem is what to write inside the back_function.